# How feasible is this human subspecies: Slimes

Tags: society, social-norms, humanoid, proto-human

Well here comes the next species after the sky dancers.

Context: A magical event has led to people with similar gene structures to humans coming around, though they can be drastically different in appearance interbreeding is possible. Despite this the magic prevents hybrids it is a simple toss of the coin.

In this question I beg a couple questions, the social repercussions of Slimes living amongst humans or near them, natural developments in society to dealing with them in day to day life and if they are even possible or if their biology needs to be changed to ensure they... work.

Gelatina sapiens

Preferred name: Slimes

Physical traits: Slimes are protohumans comprised of a gelatinous liquid body mass. This can make them somewhat difficult to kill as it would require sizeable chunks of their body mass be separated. The colour their slime adopts the colour of one of their parents. There is whole rainbow to choose from

Relationships with humans: slimes are an odd race, they tend to get patronised by most and tend to seem more like accessories by most high classed human societies. It is fashionable to be friends with a slime. This is very much down to how much of an oddity they are. They are treated more like pets than people, many seem to forget that they are just humans.

Miscellaneous information: Because slimes are comprised of mostly water, they cannot swim. Water would dilute them to the point of death. They are also very hard to kill as splitting them in half just causes the slime to form back together unless the slime properly separated a good distance

Are they feasable or are changes required?

Comment: *"In this question I beg a couple questions"* - please don't. One question per question is a rule here.

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding! You can edit your question with the little grey "edit"-button at the end of your post. Please focus on one question and remember that asking about the impact on society is almost always too broad for this Q&A format. If you have a moment please [take the tour](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour) and [visit the help center](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help) to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: So you're essentially asking if a human jellyfish cross is possible? I would go with no.

Comment: "Slimes are protohumans comprised of a gelatinous liquid body mass. " This is *not* a race a remotely like humans.  You really need to research what defines a race as being part of [the genus Homo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homo).  You can't just arbitrarily create interbreeding species like this - you're not world building if you're being arbitrary.

Comment: Somebody's been playing too much minecraft!

Answer (score 1):

In short: No

Let's start with the fact that you need some kind of skin to protect yourself from the rest of the environment and the pathogens in the air.

You need specialized organs to be able to generate enough energy to maintain your metabolism, specially the brain.

And then you have the problems that come with the locomotion and how this creature could move if it don't have muscles.

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding *Sasha*! If you have a moment please [take the tour](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour) and [visit the help center](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help) to learn more about the site. Have fun!